# ASP.NET MVC5 - Html.ActionLink with Parameters and Fragment fails to fire Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a link on a MVC5 View that is supposed to fire the event to the Controller with the selected `ID` as a parameter. After the Controller executes, it will return the same view with new results. This is working just fine, and the page rendered with the refresh data.

Now I'd like to render the page but position the page on the anchor it was.

So the code below works (fires the event and passes the controller the ID, but renders the page back to the top - notice the **fragment: null**):

```
 @Html.ActionLink(@Html.Raw(item.Nome).ToString(), "Index", "Home", protocol: null, hostName: null, fragment: null, routeValues: new { @tribe = item.ID }, htmlAttributes: null)
```

The next code places the page on the Anchor, but doesn't fire the event (the request doesn't get to the Controller):

```
 @Html.ActionLink(@Html.Raw(item.Nome).ToString(), "Index", "Home", protocol: null, hostName: null, fragment: "squads", routeValues: new { @tribe = item.ID }, htmlAttributes: null)
```

Any help would be appreciated.